Combine heat map data and different markers data in one Google Map
Can you combine heat map & markers on one Google Map? The heat map will show crime incidents while the markers need to show neighborhood watch members.
So far I can get either or of them to show, I have an idea that I'm not grasping the concept of Google Map layers correctly.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

var map, heatmap;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: { lat: -28.504330, lng: 27.931830 },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: getPoints(),
    map: map
  });

  heatmap.set('radius', 15);

// Create a pin element.
const pin = new PinElement({
    scale: 1.5,
});
// Create a marker and apply the element.
const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
    position: { lat: -28.506650, lng: 27.941490 },

});


}


function getPoints() {
  return [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-28.504440, 27.932060),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-28.504330, 27.931829)
  ];
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&signed_in=true&libraries=visualization,marker&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>




I get javascript errors with the posted code: ReferenceError: PinElement is not defined.
Then: ReferenceError: AdvancedMarkerElement is not defined

I get errors with your code:

ReferenceError: PinElement is not defined
Then:
ReferenceError: AdvancedMarkerElement is not defined

If I include the libraries per the AdvancedMarkerElement example, the marker and the heatmap both appear.
    async function initMap()  {
      // Request needed libraries.
      const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
      const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
      const { Visualization } = await google.maps.importLibrary("visualization");


code snippet:


var map, heatmap;

async function initMap() {
  // Request needed libraries.
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  const { Visualization } = await google.maps.importLibrary("visualization");

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {
      lat: -28.504330,
      lng: 27.931830
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0"
  });

  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: getPoints(),
    map: map
  });

  heatmap.set('radius', 15);
  // Create a marker and apply the element.
  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
    position: {
      lat: -28.506650,
      lng: 27.941490
    },
  });
}
function getPoints() {
  return [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-28.504440, 27.932060),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-28.504330, 27.931829)
  ];
}
initMap();
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
  </script>
     <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "weekly"});</script>
</body>

</html>



